# How to avoid 'deprecation waring' on moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have multiple format of date data like these below.

1. 20-02-01 22:12:13
2. 2020-02-01 (fri) 22:12:13
3. 2020/02/01 (fri) 22:12:13
4. 2020/02/01 22:12

I want refine those format data to 'YYYY/DD/MM hh:mm' format.

thus i put those unrefined data to moment.js!

```
date = moment(date).format('YYYY-DD-MM HH:mm');
```

then moment gave this warning below.

```
deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
Arguments: 
[0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false, _l: undefined, _i: 2020/02/03 22:52:28, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]
Error
    at Function.createFromInputFallback (/Users/loganlee/project/portfolio/back_stastics/backend/node_modules/moment/moment.js:320:98)
    at configFromString (/Users/loganlee/project/portfolio/back_stastics/backend/node_modules/moment/moment.js:2385:15)
    at configFromInput (/Users/loganlee/project/portfolio/back_stastics/backend/node_modules/moment/moment.js:2611:13)
    at prepareConfig (/Users/loganlee/project/portfolio/back_stastics/backend/node_modules/moment/moment.js:2594:13)
    at createFromConfig (/Users/loganlee/project/portfolio/back_stastics/backend/node_modules/moment/moment.js:2561:44)
    at createLocalOrUTC (/Users/loganlee/project/portfolio/back_stastics/backend/node_modules/moment/moment.js:2648:16)
    at createLocal (/Users/loganlee/project/portfolio/back_stastics/backend/node_modules/moment/moment.js:2652:16)
    at hooks (/Users/loganlee/project/portfolio/back_stastics/backend/node_modules/moment/moment.js:12:29)
    at /Users/loganlee/project/portfolio/back_stastics/backend/src/PreProcessor/index.js:263:15
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

I can do refine manually but... the step that i have to refine date data to put into moment() and refine the data to ISO  or RFC2822 format to put that into moment() also feels like wasting.

Please tell me if there is a way to use moment.js in wise way!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "*To work around this issue, specify a format for the string being passed to moment().*" - eg `moment($("#date").val(), 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss a')` - you need to specify the format *as* you parse it.

Comment: How can i deal with multiple unrefined date data if i have to specify the format about date that i give to moment()?

if I have  4 different format of date data then should i need to use switch for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid that warning whether you put any format of data

- 20-02-01 22:12:13
- 2020-02-01 (fri) 22:12:13
- 2020/02/01 (fri) 22:12:13
- 2020/02/01    22:12

there is no deprecation warning with below code.

```
date = moment(date,'YYYY-DD-MM HH:mm').format('YYYY-DD-MM HH:mm');
```

I can't sure this way is the best to solve but unless you don't need to refine data before put into moment()!